# Handler changing UI causes CalledFromWrongThreadException

Tags: java, android, multithreading, garbage-collection, handler

I've created a `Handler` that can be accessed from anywhere within the activity and also written a method to make it easier to call the handler:

```
private Handler textFromBGThread = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage (Message msg) {
        // Get the string from the msg
        String outputString = msg.getData().getString("Output");
        // Find the TextView
        TextView Output = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.ConsoleOutputView);
        // Display the output
        Log.i("TextOutput","About to display message: " + outputString);
        Output.setText(Output.getText() + outputString);
        Log.i("TextOutput","Message displayed");
    }
};

private void TextOutputWrapper (String outputText) {
    Message msg = new Message();
    Bundle bndle = new Bundle();
    bndle.putString("Output", "\n" + outputText);
    msg.setData(bndle);
    textFromBGThread.handleMessage(msg);
}
```

So then this can be called from a background thread simply with:

```
TextOutputWrapper("Attemping to connect...");
```

This will work 1+ times, however, the actual visual change will cause a `CalledFromWrongThreadException` to be thrown. Being new to Java & Android, I'm stuck on why this is happening.

I have noticed that the crash tends to happen when there's a slightly longer time period between calls & that if the calls to `TextOutputWrapper(String)` are happening very quickly after one another, then it works. For example, this:

```
int i = 0;
while (i < 200) {
    TextOutputWrapper(String.valueOf(i));
    i++;
}
```

works fine.

Having looked at LogCat, it seems that the garbage collector frees up some resources and then the next time `TextOutputWrapper(String)` is called, it crashes (when `Output.SetText(String)` is called, to be precise), although I'm not exactly sure why that would cause this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a few things I'd change here:

### Using Handler

A `Handler` is useful if you want to trigger the UI to update, and do so from a **non-UI thread** (*aka* "background" thread).

In your case, it's not serving that purpose.  You are **directly** calling

```
textFromBGThread.handleMessage(msg);
```

It's not designed for you to do that.  The way you are supposed to use `Handler` is to implement what you want done to the UI in the `handleMessage(Message)` method.  You did that.  But, you shouldn't *directly* call `handleMessage()`.  If you do that, then `handleMessage()` will be called from whatever thread invokes `TextOutputWrapper()`.  **If that's a background thread, then that's wrong.**

What you want to do is to call the handler's [sendMessage(Message)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#sendMessage%28android.os.Message%29) method (or one of the other available variants).  `sendMessage()` will put your message in a thread-safe queue, that is then processed on the main thread.  The main thread will then invoke your handler's `handleMessage()`, passing it back the queued message, and allowing it to safely change the UI.  So, change `TextOutputWrapper()` to use this:

```
private void TextOutputWrapper (String outputText) {
    Message msg = new Message();
    Bundle bndle = new Bundle();
    bndle.putString("Output", "\n" + outputText);
    msg.setData(bndle);
    textFromBGThread.sendMessage(msg);
}
```

### Java Conventions

This code is a bit hard to read, for an experienced Java developer.  In Java, [typical coding standards](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#367) reserve upper case names for things like classes, while methods start with lower case letters.  So, please rename the method to:

```
private void textOutputWrapper (String outputText);
```

or, better yet, since this is in fact a method, and not a wrapper, *per se*, rename to something like

```
private void outputText(String text);
```

### Safe Threading Alternatives

Finally, I might recommend that if you simply want a method that allows you to safely modify the UI from any thread, use another technique.  I don't find `Handler` to be that easy to use for beginners.

```
private void outputText(final String outputString) {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Find the TextView
            TextView output = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.ConsoleOutputView);
            // Display the output
            Log.i("TextOutput","About to display message: " + outputString);
            output.setText(Output.getText() + outputString);
            Log.i("TextOutput","Message displayed");
        }
    });
}
```

`runOnUiThread()` is a method available in every `Activity`.

I'll also point you to some general docs on understanding threading in Android:

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/05/painless-threading.html